Is this calculus derivation process correct?
This is part of the economics romer model, finding the Lagrangian value
$$\mathcal{L}=\int_{i=0}^Ap(i)L(i)di-\lambda([\int_{i=0}^AL(i)^\phi di]^{\frac{1}{\phi}}-1)\\
s.t.\int_{i=0}^{A}L(i)^{\phi}di=1
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dL}&=\int_{i=0}^{A}p(i)di-\lambda\frac{1}{\phi}\bigg[\int_{i=0}^{A}L(i)^{\phi}di\bigg]^{\frac{1}{\phi}-1}\bigg[\phi\int_{i=0}^{A}L(i)^{\phi-1}di\bigg] \\
&=\int_{i=0}^{A}p(i)di-\lambda\int_{i=0}^{A}L(i)^{\phi-1}di=0
\end{aligned}
$$
so we get
$$p(i)=\lambda L(i)^{\phi-1} $$

How do you contract the product of the power of a sum with another sum?  $$\left(\sum_i a_i^k\right)^n (\sum_j a_j^{k-1})$$
